# Python Array alignment always the same output, even with different input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Alright, so obviously I've done something hilariously wrong here. But I don't get what's the problem.

Here is the idea:  I have 3 3D Arrays, that all have a slightly different size. I need them all to have the same shape (I'm putting them into a CNN later on, that's why).
So I wanted to create a Array that is filled with 0's that has a shape that can accomodate exery single array. With this I get 3 Arrays that are of the same size and are padded with 0's.

But the Problem is: whenever I call this function, all three outputs are the output of the last call. The Information of the previous calls get's lost. 
I do not understand what's wrong with the code. The previous calls should not have access to the third call, why do they have the same Information in them?

Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np

def al_array(array, big_arr):
    diff_z = (big_arr.shape[0] - array.shape[0]) // 2
    diff_x = (big_arr.shape[1] - array.shape[1]) // 2
    diff_y = (big_arr.shape[2] - array.shape[2]) // 2
    end_z = diff_z + array.shape[0]
    end_x = diff_x + array.shape[1]
    end_y = diff_y + array.shape[2]

    big_arr[diff_z:end_z,diff_x:end_x,diff_y:end_y] = array
    return big_arr

def get_array(shapes):
    z = np.amax(shapes[:,0])
    x = np.amax(shapes[:,1])
    y = np.amax(shapes[:,2])
    out = np.zeros((z,x,y))
    return out
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = np.random.randint(5, size=(3,4, 8))
    a2 = np.random.randint(5, size=(2,3, 5))
    a3 = np.random.randint(5, size=(2,6, 4))
    print(a1.shape)
    zero_arr=get_array(np.asarray([np.asarray(a1.shape),np.asarray(a2.shape),np.asarray(a3.shape)]))
    print(zero_arr)
    ab1 = al_array(a1, zero_arr)
    ab2 = al_array(a2, zero_arr)
    ab3 = al_array(a3, zero_arr)
    print(ab1)
    print((np.equal(ab1,ab2)))
```

Comment: You seem to be expecting a lot of implicit copies. Unlike languages like C or C++, Python mostly doesn't make implicit copies; `ab1`, `ab2`, `ab3`, and `zero_arr` all refer to the same array.

Comment: Yeah that was actually the Problem. creating a new zer_arr in each call of "al_array" fixed the issue